# Create pattern node with Json SchemaGenerator as JsonNode

Tags: java, json

I'm generating a complete JSON tree from root of an object with several nested objects by using the SchemaGenerator (https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator). In one of these nested objects I have a String property that should fulfill a certain pattern.

```
public class ClassA {
   @Pattern(regexp = "^[1-9][0-9]*$")
   private String someString;
   private String anotherString;
}
```

My goal is, to have this Json node:

```
"properties": {
    "someString": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "^[1-9][0-9]*$"
    },
    "anotherString": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}, ...
```

Is there a simple way to do this with the SchemaGenerator without explicitly adding the node "pattern" in the Json node? Perhaps by using either another annotation on the String or by adding a specific option to the SchemaGenerator.

Or is there another way to do this "automagically"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am using the victools/jsonschema-generator framework, there is a SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder which can be configured by using a JavaxValidationModule. This module can be set with options. And one of this option (INCLUDE_PATTERN_EXPRESSIONS) creates exactly this nod that I need.